# Why downloadable file name contain hash

Tags: opencart2.x

Uploaded filename in `Catalog-->Downloads` section are like this:
`Chrysanthemum.jpg.bafd8619f8e86bba3b8c90063b2910d2`

in this example `Chrysanthemum.jpg`  is filename and What's usage this: `.bafd8619f8e86bba3b8c90063b2910d2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about Opencart I would say that it's an easy way to make sure that if you upload two images with the same name but different content they won't replace each other. If it's indeed a hash of the content thats appended then that would also ensure that if you upload the same image twice it will still only be stored once.

Comment: In wordpress when you upload repetitive filename. the filename will append 1, 2, 3 ..   like this: file.jpg, file1.jpg, file2.jpg , ... i think it would be better. :)

Comment: Well if you simply append a number to it then you could upload the same file ten times and end up with ten files, if you can match it on the file hash then you would save disk space (and bandwidth for your users since you can reuse the same image which they might have cached already).

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer then you can mark it as accepted. You could of course also wait and see if you get more answers later on (in which case you can change the accepted answer if you want to).

Comment: This is not about image, it's about files which will be downloadable products  after uploading so using hash after their name (you can check it's after ext.) secure it more than just simple save because in store you don't want to free download any songs or game ;) and of course Karl point is valid too but OC didn't give a shit about same name, at time of image upload it devilishly replace images.